# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with the symfony 2.5.12 application. Only in the production version I get the error:

```html
admin@00:/home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl$ php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener' not found in /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:145
Stack trace:
#0 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(455): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService('sensio_framewor...', 'Sensio\\Bundle\\F...')
#1 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2090): appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService()
#2 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(86): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('event_dispatche...')
#3 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->do in /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php on line 145

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener' not found in /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:145
Stack trace:
#0 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php(455): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->addSubscriberService('sensio_framewor...', 'Sensio\\Bundle\\F...')
#1 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2090): appProdProjectContainer->getEventDispatcherService()
#2 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php(86): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('event_dispatche...')
#3 /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(124): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->do in /home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php on line 145
admin@00:/home/users/adevo/public_html/przykladowastrona.pl$
```

When I try to clean the cache for the prod version I also get this error

```
php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod
```

Comment: What is "the production version" exactly…? How does it differ from the non-production version?

Comment: do you get same error with: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`? maybe if you have other version the console directory is in Bin so the new one is `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: try to do `php app/console --version`

Comment: How did you deploy your project? did you have problem while installing your vendors?  `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`?

Comment: 1. I understand the production version without app_dev.php
2. when I try `php app / console cache: clear --env = prod` too I get this error
3. "php app / console --version" command gave the result: `Symfony version 2.5.12 - app / dev / debug`
4. At the beginning of the construction of the project, the "prod" version worked correctly, the error appeared during creation

Comment: When i try use command php `app/console assetic:dump --env="prod"` I get this error

Comment: there is someone who could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove Folder Cache with FTP Serwer